# SQL Getting User Max & The Rest Of The column

Tags: sql

```
EntryID, UserID, UserAmt, UserCode
1, 100, 5, 888
2, 101, 10, 777
3, 101, 5, 666
4, 102, 5, 555
```

OK So I need every UserId's highest "UserAmt", and also the corresponding UserCode...

```
1, 100, 5, 888
2, 101, 10, 777
4, 102, 5, 555
```

However, the highest code isn't always the highest UserAmt.

Answer (score 1):

IS easy using `row_number` and `partition by`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6dc59b/1)**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT [EntryID], 
              [UserID], 
              [UserAmt], 
              [UserCode], 
              ROW_NUMBER() over  
                  (PARTITION BY [UserID] ORDER BY [UserAmt] DESC) as RN
       FROM Table1
     ) as T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: There is one thing author didn't specify, mutliple values like http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/18206/2/0 and it is always dilema `ROW_NUMBER` vs `RANK`

Comment: Hi @lad2025. Not sure if your comment is regarding the answer or the question.

Comment: It is rather about question `what if there is ... `. Something like `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, but it depends on author needs. Your solution is ok

Comment: One more thing author does not specify which RDBMS he uses, so it may fail for example with MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
   select UserID, max(UserAmt) as max_amount  
   from your_table 
   group by UserID
) t2 on t1.UserID = t2.UserID and t1.UserAmt = t2.max_amount
```

Comment: No, I don't have it twice. `t1.*` is not `*`